# Comparar arquivos na pasta e deletar específicos em Python

Tags: python-3.x

Sou bem iniciante e estou com uma dúvida em uma situação que estou criando, se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

Estou tentando desenvolver um programa em Python que resolva meu estresse diário de deletar alguns arquivos em pastas.
Eu tenho que verificar os arquivos pelo nome nesse formato:

- 01 - Carlos
- 01 - TSE
- 02 - João
- 02 - TSE
- 03 - TSE
- 04 - Maria
- 04 - TSE

Deletando os "TSE" que tem número igual a nomes e deixando os "TSE" que não tem outro aruivo com mesmo número, a lista ficaria assim:

- 01 - Carlos
- 02 - João
- 03 - TSE
- 04 - Maria

Eu até consigo deletar todos os arquivos que tenham TSE no nome, mas deveria deixar aqueles que não tem correspondência com nomes numerados.
Meu código está assim:

```
from time import sleep
import os
import glob

pasta = os.getcwd()
tipo = '*.txt'
texto = 'TSE'
arquivos = glob.glob1(pasta, tipo)

n = 1
y = 1
ok = int(input(f'''
<====>\033[1;31mOS arquivos "{tipo}" com "{texto}" em seus nomes serão DELETADOS!\033[m<====>
\n
\033[0;33m[1] OK
[2] CANCELAR\033[m \n
Opção: '''))
if ok == 1:
    for x in arquivos:
        txnum = str(n).zfill(2)
        if texto and txnum in x:
            os.remove(arq)
            print(f'Arquivo "{x}" DELETADO!!')
            print('=' * 20)
    n += 1
print('Finalizando o Programa!!')
sleep (3)
exit()
```

Comment: Eu iria sugerir que, primeiro, criar um array com todos os nomes dos arquivos na pasta, então iterar esse array e verificar se aquele arquivo termina em TSE e tem algum item na lista que começe pelo numéro do arquivo, pulando, é claro, o item da iteração

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Código:

```
    #Ponto 1:
    for indice in range(len(arquivos)-1):
    
      #Ponto 2
      if arquivos[indice][:3] == arquivos[indice + 1][:3]:

        #Ponto 3:           
        if texto in arquivos[indice + 1]:
            os.remove(arquivos[indice + 1])
            print(f'Arquivo "{arquivos[indice + 1]}" DELETADO!!')
            print('=' * 20)
```

### Ponto 1:

Mudando o laço e usando um **for i in range(len(x))** ao invés de **for i in x**. Usamos isso sempre que precisamos fazer comparações entre os itens da lista. Dessa forma temos uma repetição controlada pelo tamanho do vetor, podendo alterar entre ps índices de cada item. Esta é importância de termos sempre os vetores ordenados, isso simplifica várias comparações dentro da lista, então, caso o a lista não esteja ordenada pelo Sistema Operacional, faça um método para isso. Mais detalhes sobre [estruturas de repetição aqui](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

### Ponto 2:

Essa linha faz a comparação entre o número do arquivo trabalhando com sub-strings. Por ser só dois digítos, usa-se o 3º caractere como ponto de parada. Para mais informações sobre strings acesse a [documentação aqui](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

### Ponto 3:

Partindo-se que a lista esta ordenada, basta apagar o arquivo da sequência, comparando antes se realmente tem o termo 'TSE' presente nele.

### Código completo:

```
from time import sleep
import os
import glob

pasta = os.getcwd()
tipo = '*.txt'
texto = 'TSE'
arquivos = glob.glob1(pasta, tipo)

n = 1
y = 1
ok = int(input(f'\033[1;31mOS arquivos "{tipo}" com "{texto}" em seus nomes serão DELETADOS!\n\n' +
                '\033[0;33m[1] OK\n[2] CANCELAR\033[m\nOpção: '))

if ok == 1:
  for indice in range(len(arquivos)-1):
    if arquivos[indice][:3] == arquivos[indice + 1][:3]:      
      if texto in arquivos[indice + 1]:
        os.remove(arquivos[indice + 1])
        print(f'Arquivo "{arquivos[indice + 1]}" DELETADO!!')
        print('=' * 20)

print('Finalizando o Programa!!')
sleep (3)
exit()
```

Comment: Entendi! Ainda sou novo na comunidade e estou me adaptando. Obrigado pelas dicas @Augusto Vasques!

Comment: Muito Obrigado Octávio, realmente parece muito mais simples a forma como vc postou. Vou tentar aqui e te dou uma resposta!

Comment: Realmente ficou top! Safou meu problema só reduzi o substring pra [:1], pq isso evita que erros na digitação do nome não apaguem ele ex (01-aasd, 01 - asd, e 01---asd, são diferentes a partir do [:3] mas iguais apartir do [:1].

Comment: Que bom que ajudei! Assim que puder, marque uma das respostas como aceita, assim outros usuários com a mesma dúvida saberão que já tem uma solução.

Comment: Octávio, fiz uma pequena alteração. Usei o [:2] ao invés de [:3] e repeti a estrutura do IF para apagar também caso o (arquivos[indice]) tenha o texto TSE e não só o (arquivos[indice+1]), pq existem casos em que a ordem fica diferente devido a classificação do Windows. Muito obrigado mesmo! Me ensinou muito!

Answer (score 2):

Não ficou claro o que deveria acontecer neste caso de exemplo:

- 01 - Carlos
- 01 - TSE
- 02 - TSE
- 02 - Maria
- 03 - Maria
- 03 - Carlos

Como se pode ver acima, existem múltiplas referências do mesmo nome em números diferentes e não existe exclusividade dos mesmos em número algum.

**Agora**, caso essa não seja uma possibilidade real, acredito que o código a seguir deve resolver seu problema:

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict

arquivos = ['01 - Carlos', '01 - TSE', '02 - Joao', '02 - TSE', '03 - TSE', '04 - Maria', '04 - TSE']

d = defaultdict(list)
l = []

formatar_arquivo = lambda num, nome: '{} - {}'.format(num, nome)

for arquivo in arquivos:
    num, nome = map(str.strip, filter(bool, arquivo.split('-')))
    arq = formatar_arquivo(num, nome)
    if arq != arquivo:
        os.rename(arquivo, arq)
    l.append(nome)
    d[num].append(nome)

for k, v in d.items():
    if len(v) == 1:
        continue
    for i in v:
        if l.count(i) == 1:
            for j in filter(lambda x: x != i, v):
                arq = formatar_arquivo(k, j)
                os.remove(arq)
            break
```

**Esta solução é compatível com Python versões 2 e 3.**

Comment: Muito obrigado Rfroes87, a resposta do Octávio safou perfeitamente minha dúvida, mas olharei seu código com calma, pois é mais complexo.